# Removing space between sum and its correspondent value with only one number representing all the equations

Tags: numbering

In fact, I want to know how can I remove space in the second sum of the first expression and also to have a good equations design represented with only one number. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
U_{c}(1) &= \sum_{n=1}^{4}( U_{e}(n)\times\sum_{k=n+10}^{14}U_{\Delta e}(k)) ; U_{c}(2)&= \sum_{n=1}^{4}U_{e}(n)\times U_{\Delta e}(n+9)\\ U_{c}(3)&= \sum_{n=1}^{6}U_{e}(n)\times U_{\Delta e}(n+8); U_{c}(4)&= \sum_{n=1}^{7}U_{e}(n)\times U_{\Delta e}(n+7)\\
U_{c}(5)&= \sum_{n=2}^{8}U_{e}(n)\times U_{\Delta e}(n+5); U_{c}(6)&= \sum_{n=3}^{7}U_{e}(n)\times U_{\Delta e}(n+5)\\
U_{c}(7)&= \sum_{n=8}^{11}( U_{e}(n)\times\sum_{k=n-4}^{7}U_{\Delta e}(k))
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

To have like:

[image]

Comment: Don't accept my answer if it doesn't really solve your problem.

Comment: I wouldn't do this. It worsens legibility a lot, since one expects the equation numbers to be at the right margin and not somewhere inside the paragraph. I wouldn't find this equation if it was referenced.

Comment: This question is not clear. The added image doesn't make it any more clear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- Use side-by-side `minipage` environments, for the groups of 4 and 3 equations, respectively
- Inside the `minipage` environments, use `equation` and `split` environments to achieve the required style of equation numbering
- Replace all `\times` directives with thinspace
- Enlarge the "outer" parentheses in the first and last equations in the left-hand-side `minipage`
- Use `\mathclap` to "snug up" the spacing around the `\sum` symbols in two cases
- Optional: replace all instances of `U_{\Delta` with `U_{\!\Delta`, to tighten up the spacing between `U` and the subscript-`\Delta` symbol

Still another suggestion/observation, echoing the remark by @Skillmon: If the large curly braces are placed to the left of the blocks of equations, as indicated by the screenshot you posted, it's not going to be easy for your readers to notice the equation numbers on the right. Assuming you want to go with the proposed layout, it may be (a lot) better if the large curly braces are placed on the *right*, so that they direct the reader's eye to the associated equation number.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\mathclap' macro
\begin{document}

%% First solution: Curly braces placed on left-hand side
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{split}
U_{c}(1)&= \sum_{n=1}^{4}\Bigl( U_{e}(n)
           \sum_{\mathclap{k=n+10}}^{14}U_{\!\Delta e}(k) \Bigr) \\ 
U_{c}(3)&= \sum_{n=1}^{6}U_{e}(n)\, U_{\!\Delta e}(n+8) \\
U_{c}(5)&= \sum_{n=2}^{8}U_{e}(n)\, U_{\!\Delta e}(n+5) \\
U_{c}(7)&= \sum_{n=8}^{11}\Bigl( U_{e}(n)
           \sum_{\mathclap{k=n-4}}^{7}U_{\!\Delta e}(k) \Bigr)
\end{split}\right.
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill  % maximize horizontal distance between the minipage environments
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\linewidth}
\begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{split}
U_{c}(2)&= \sum_{n=1}^{4}U_{e}(n)\, U_{\!\Delta e}(n+9)\\
U_{c}(4)&= \sum_{n=1}^{7}U_{e}(n)\, U_{\!\Delta e}(n+7)\\
U_{c}(6)&= \sum_{n=3}^{7}U_{e}(n)\, U_{\!\Delta e}(n+5)
\end{split}\right.
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}

%% Second solution: Curly braces placed on right-hand side
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{equation}
\left.\begin{split}
U_{c}(1)&= \sum_{n=1}^{4}\Bigl( U_{e}(n)
           \sum_{\mathclap{k=n+10}}^{14}U_{\!\Delta e}(k) \Bigr) \\ 
U_{c}(3)&= \sum_{n=1}^{6}U_{e}(n)\, U_{\!\Delta e}(n+8) \\
U_{c}(5)&= \sum_{n=2}^{8}U_{e}(n)\, U_{\!\Delta e}(n+5) \\
U_{c}(7)&= \sum_{n=8}^{11}\Bigl( U_{e}(n)
           \sum_{\mathclap{k=n-4}}^{7}U_{\!\Delta e}(k) \Bigr)
\end{split}\right\}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill  % maximize horizontal distance between the minipage environments
\begin{minipage}{0.47\linewidth}
\begin{equation}
\left.\begin{split}
U_{c}(2)&= \sum_{n=1}^{4}U_{e}(n)\, U_{\!\Delta e}(n+9)\\
U_{c}(4)&= \sum_{n=1}^{7}U_{e}(n)\, U_{\!\Delta e}(n+7)\\
U_{c}(6)&= \sum_{n=3}^{7}U_{e}(n)\, U_{\!\Delta e}(n+5)
\end{split}\right\}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very useful tips indeed. Still wouldn't do the second tag inside of the text block. This is bound to annoy readers.

Comment: @Skillmon - I fully agree with your comment. I've augmented my answer to post a second solution, with the curly braces placed on the right, pointing towards the associated equation numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much @miko I liked the second solution since the expressions on the right are on the center but how can I have the curly braces on the left ?

Comment: @kerdoujkardouj - I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "expressions ... are on the center" or why you ask, "how can I have the curly braces on the left?". The first solution shows exactly how to place the curly braces on the left, doesn't it? And why do you write that you like the second solution, while evidently not liking its placement of the curly braces on the right? Please clarify.

Comment: In fact @Mico you propose two solutions, the first one is the one that I want but as you can see there are 4 expressions on the left summarized by (1) and 3 expressions on the right sumarized by (2). The problem is that both expressions (1) and (2) are aligned. What I actually want is to have the expressions on the right summarized by (2) to be on the center of the (1). In the second solution this is the form that I want but the curly braces are on the right but I want them on the left.

Comment: @kerdoujkardouj - I'm afraid I don't understand your additional comments. E.g., what do you mean by "aligned" and "centered"?

Comment: @Mico, eveyrthing is fine I just want the second solution but with curly braces on the right and not in the left. You have used the curly braces in the right

Comment: @kerdoujkardouj - Taking the second solution as a starting point, is there anything stopping you from changing `\left.` to `\left\{` and `\right\}` to `\right.`?

Comment: Great it works fine now thank you very much @Mico, I just didn't know about the command I was changing \left. to \right. and \left\{ to \right\{

Comment: 12 Apr 2023: The 10th upvote on this answer earned me the 1,900th badge in all on this site. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

The space is caused by the sum's subscript. If you remove the subscript's width, you get tight spacing. Also you miss an additional `&` in places where you put a `;`, to start a new column with the alignment at the `=`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\left[\begin{aligned}
  U_{c}(1) &= \sum_{n=1}^{4}( U_{e}(n)\times\sum_{\mathclap{k=n+10}}^{14}U_{\Delta e}(k)) ;& U_{c}(2)&= \sum_{n=1}^{4}U_{e}(n)\times U_{\Delta e}(n+9)\\
  U_{c}(3)&= \sum_{n=1}^{6}U_{e}(n)\times U_{\Delta e}(n+8) ;& U_{c}(4)&= \sum_{n=1}^{7}U_{e}(n)\times U_{\Delta e}(n+7)\\
U_{c}(5)&= \sum_{n=2}^{8}U_{e}(n)\times U_{\Delta e}(n+5) ;& U_{c}(6)&= \sum_{n=3}^{7}U_{e}(n)\times U_{\Delta e}(n+5)\\
U_{c}(7)&= \sum_{n=8}^{11}( U_{e}(n)\times\sum_{k=n-4}^{7}U_{\Delta e}(k))
\end{aligned}\right]
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But why is U_c(2) far from its expression and also I want these equations to be reprsented by one number instead of 4 with one bracket

Comment: @kerdoujkardouj that is because you miss an additional `&`. See my edit. Not sure whether I got your second half right this time, though.

Comment: Ah okay thank you very much @Skillmon, if I want to represent the pair expressions inside a bracket how can I do it

Comment: @kerdoujkardouj adding a bit of kerning next to the brackets might enhance the look.

Comment: can you please look at the edit so you can see what I want to do

Comment: I think it's necessary to enlarge the outer parentheses in the expressions for U(1) and U(7). I would also omit the semicolons.

Comment: @Mico I thought about the semicolons, but eventually kept them. The spacing of the braces should be considered, you're right.